# Should I say "at a low price" or "at a low cost"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to place an ad to sell my services. Should I say I have good service at a low *price* or low *cost*?

Comment: In addition to the points in the answers, don't say you "have good service". Why would anyone care what kind of service you have? They care what kind of service you provide or offer *them*. So you want say "I *provide* good service" or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Low price***.

*Price* is what you charge; *cost* is what the buyer winds up paying, which may be more or less than the price, and in any event is not under your control.

See [this paper](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) for entirely too many details about these words, as well as *worth* and *value*.

Comment: In fact, either would suffice for advertising. I've seen plenty of ads for "low-cost" solutions or products, and I somehow knew what they were talking about.

Comment: I agree that it should be "price." In retail lingo, *price* is the amount of money that a buyer pays for an item.  However, you say that "cost" is what the buyer pays, but that isn't so. "Cost" is the seller's expense for obtaining goods to sell, not the buyer's.  It seems that you say this in your paper, but your answer is not so clear.  However, I am willing to admit that I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: That's one interpretation, from the seller's viewpoint. From the buyer's viewpoint it's a different interpretation. And you want to appeal to the buyer's viewpoint in advertising. They don't care how the seller does the accounting.

Comment: But the simple truth is, if you tell me something will be "low-cost" to me, I assume I won't have to pay a lot.

Comment: If you believe me. I could be lying, of course, which is what marketing is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Low Price over Low Cost.

Low cost implies low quality or the low end solution. Low price implies a bargain.

People get a lot more excited about bargains than products that are cheap because they don't cost much. A low cost good is something that has little value. A low priced good may actually cost less than it's value.

Comment: The standard usage for *goods* in your context is always plural. You never buy/sell *"**a** good"*. Also, **it's** means **it is**, not *belonging to it*.